# Django request.user returning None

Tags: django, request

I have a user, the one I'm logged in. This user is called "chau". He follows another user, one called "hola". Im sure about this. I checked it in Django Admin.

So i'm trying to do this:

```
def followings(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        print(request.user.follows)
```

But i'm getting `network.User.None` I don`t know why. I checked literally 20 times to see if `request.user` does not follow anybody, but he does!

Down here is my model structure:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    follows = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='followed_by')
```

I did make migrations, and it said that were already applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `user.follows` is a `Manager`, no a `QuerySet`, you should add `.all()` at the end:

```
def followings(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        print(request.user.follows.all())
```